# How to conditionally set first InstType in Component page

Tags: nsis

I want to conditionally set the first Installation type in Component page based on checking if some files already exists on the machine.

I've already tried two different approachs. 1) using SetCurInstType, 2) conditionally defining the InstType sequence order on the basis of a "file exist" check.

Both the approaches have been tested using an UDF function. This UDF function has been used, alternatively, as input for the MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE of MUI_PAGE_LICENSE and for the MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE of MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS.

Both tests didn't work as expected

Approach 1)

```
InstType "Install (all)"
InstType "Install (minimal)"
    !define USER_ALL_INST_TYPE 1
    !define USER_MIN_INST_TYPE 2

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SetInitInstType
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

Section "1" Sec1 
    SectionIn ${USER_ALL_INST_TYPE} ${USER_MIN_INST_TYPE}

    ... other code

SectionEnd

Section "2" Sec2 
    SectionIn ${USER_ALL_INST_TYPE}

    ... other code

SectionEnd

Function SetInitInstType
    IfFileExists "<file_path>" 0 endSetInitInstType
    SetCurInstType ${USER_MIN_INST_TYPE}

    endSetInitInstType:
FunctionEnd
```

Approach 2)

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SetInitInstType
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

Section "1" Sec1 
    SectionIn ${USER_ALL_INST_TYPE} ${USER_MIN_INST_TYPE}

    ... other code

SectionEnd

Section "2" Sec2 
    SectionIn ${USER_ALL_INST_TYPE}

    ... other code

SectionEnd

Function SetInitInstType
    IfFileExists "<file_path>" 0 SetAllInstType
    InstType "Install (minimal)"
    InstType "Install (all)"
        !define USER_MIN_INST_TYPE 1
        !define USER_ALL_INST_TYPE 2

    Goto endSetInitInstType

    SetAllInstType:
    InstType "Install (all)"
    InstType "Install (minimal)"
        !define USER_ALL_INST_TYPE 1
        !define USER_MIN_INST_TYPE 2

    endSetInitInstType:
FunctionEnd
```

After Condition check, if file existed, the expected result would be that the Install Mode ComboBox in Component page was initialized with the "Install (minimal)" option

The actual result is instead as follow:

Approach 1) --> All sections are disabled and the Install Mode ComboBox is initialized with the "Custom" option

Approach 2) --> I receive an error during script compiling

```
Section: "1" ->(Sec1)
SectionIn: Usage: SectionIn InstTypeIdx [InstTypeIdx [...]]
Error in script "<script_name>.nsi" on line XXX -- aborting creation process
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: Maybe try to resolve some of your previous questions before asking new questions?

Comment: AFAIK I have no pending questions (I don't have any error during scripting compiling regarding other points). If you refer  to other questions I did before in this forum I don't have action points on those. Do I have formally close in some way that questions? If not, please tell me what you mean. Many thanks

Comment: You don't have to but ideally you should mark questions as answered if the answer is acceptable or add comments and clarifications if not.

Comment: Hi Anders - I found where to specify if the question was answered or not, then I marked those questions as answered. Thanks for the information. Coming back to the point, my code, before this change, works like a charm, so no other issue is in my script at moment. Do you have any suggestion for this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me why but `SectionIn` uses a different index system than all the other inst type functions.

> Unlike SectionIn the index is zero based, which means the first install type's index is 0

```
!include MUI2.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SetInitInstType
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

!macro AddInstType name text
!define /IfNDef AddInstType_COUNTER 0
InstType "${text}"
!define INSTTYPE_${name}_IDX ${AddInstType_COUNTER} ; For SetCurInstType etc.
!define /ReDef /Math AddInstType_COUNTER ${AddInstType_COUNTER} + 1
!define INSTTYPE_${name}_SIN ${AddInstType_COUNTER} ; For SectionIn
!macroend

!insertmacro AddInstType ALL "Install (all)"
!insertmacro AddInstType MIN "Install (minimal)"

Section "1 (Both)" Sec1 
SectionIn ${INSTTYPE_ALL_SIN} ${INSTTYPE_MIN_SIN}
SectionEnd

Section "2 (All only)" Sec2 
SectionIn ${INSTTYPE_ALL_SIN}
SectionEnd

Function SetInitInstType
    IfFileExists "$WinDir\Explorer.exe" 0 +2
        SetCurInstType ${INSTTYPE_MIN_IDX}
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
    Call SetInitInstType ; In case installer is silent, force correct sections
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It works... with a nice coding solution too. Tks Anders